# Fluid Typography

Tags: html, css, typography

I'm trying to use fluid typography and the goal is to scale the text between screen sizes 300px and 1160px.

So at 1160px I want 56px H1 and mobile 30px.

The problem I'm having is the H1 increases in size past the 1160px and keeps increasing.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: calc(30px + (56 - 30) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1160 - 300)));
}
```

```html
<H1>Fluid Typography</H1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to limit fluid calculation of `h1` between media queries. Try this:

```
h1 { font-size: 30px; }

@media (min-width: 300px) { 
  h1 {
    font-size: calc(30px + (56 - 30) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1160 - 300)));    
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1160px) { 
  h1 {
    font-size: 56px; 
  }
}
```

First, the minimum font-size needs to be provided: that's the first line. Then between two breakpoints you introduce fluid calculation which, at `300px` gives exactly `30px` of `font-size`, and again at `1160px` calculates to exactly `56px`. After `1160px` you keep it at `56px` again using media query. This way you have a graceful transition between static and fluid typography between the set breakpoints.

You can find more examples of this here: 
https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/fluid-type-calc-examples/
or here:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/

Let me know if you need more examples, I've done a lot of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SCSS you can use the following Mixin:
https://gist.github.com/MColl92/3229098c32e20c1d5593865a7e3ea3da

```
$min_screen_width: 360px;
$max_screen_width: 1448px;
$min_font_size: 38px;
$max_font_size: 52px;

@mixin fluid-type($min-vw, $max-vw, $min-font-size, $max-font-size) {
  $u1: unit($min-vw);
  $u2: unit($max-vw);
  $u3: unit($min-font-size);
  $u4: unit($max-font-size);

  @if $u1 == $u2 and $u1 == $u3 and $u1 == $u4 {
    & {
      font-size: $min-font-size;
      @media screen and (min-width: $min-vw) {
        font-size: calc(
          #{$min-font-size} + #{strip-unit($max-font-size - $min-font-size)}*
            ((100vw - #{$min-vw}) / #{strip-unit($max-vw - $min-vw)})
        );
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: $max-vw) {
        font-size: $max-font-size;
      }
    }
  }
}

@function strip-unit($value) {
  @return $value / ($value * 0 + 1);
}
```

To apply globally:

1. Define your minimum and maximum screen widths
2. Define your min and max font size for H1 element in px
3. Apply fluid-type mixin to root element (html or body selector).
4. Generate px to rem table from https://nekocalc.com/px-to-rem-converter. 
   (NOTE: you will need to set the root font size to you max_font_size when generating)
5. Assign REM values to font-size as required

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2023**

As CSS progresses, there is no longer need to use media queries because CSS now offers the `clamp(min, calc, max)` function:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: clamp(30px, 30px + (56 - 30) * (100vw - 300px) / (1160 - 300), 56px);
}
```

```html
<h1>Fluid Typography</h1>
```